# "an idea" or "the idea" of doing something

Tags: articles

Does "idea" have always go with "the"?

> 1. Do you like the idea of making some money on the side?

or can it be

> 2. Do you like an idea of making some money on the side?

When can we use "an idea of doing"?

Answer (score 1):

Since the idea is specifically related to making money, a definite article must be used. **The definite article (the) is used before a noun to indicate that the identity of the noun is known to the reader.**

> Do you like **the** idea of making some money on the side?

This statement indicates that you have already an idea proposed to you by someone or an idea made up in your mind on how to make more money.

> Do you like **an** idea of making some money on the side?

This sounds like the addresser is asking the addressee about any general idea of making money.

Comment: It's hard to see for me why an idea which has just struck me is specific? I still don't see what makes it specific. Is it that I have a plan on which to carry it out or what?

Comment: The idea here is idiomatic. It actually is meaning that you have devised a plan for making more side money or whatever it is that you have thought upon. So that does make it specific.